# map a request response in python twisted

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.client

I have started to learn Python twisted. I have a basic requirement to map the request and response for a TCP client. The client can send any request anytime based on some condition and it expects a specific response for that request from a server. How I could map a request-response pair. A sample code of what I want. Also, the server could send an arbitrary message which does not map to any of client request.

```
class MSOProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client_id = uuid4()
        self.messagePair = collections.OrderedDict()

    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("Device connected to TSIF")
        self.doOperation()              

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        log.msg('Device lost connection because {}'.format(reason))

    def sendMessage(self, data):
        log.msg('Device sending...str(msg)'.format(data))
        self.transport.write(data)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        log.msg('Device received {}'.format(data))
        #how do I map the response with my request

    def doOperation(self):
        CONDITION = "rainy"
        if condition == "sunny":
            self.sendMessage("sunny weather")


class DeviceFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MSOProtocol()

def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 16000, DeviceFactory())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not clear, what do you mean. You just immediately respond to each request and that's it.

Comment: It could be that the server has sent the response for earlier request done in the past whose response the client does not care anymore and wanted to have the response of the current request.

Comment: Look at the implementation of twisted.protocols.amp (which does all the things you ask about)